# How to separate broker-url from its parameters (ActiveMQ Artemis + Spring Boot)

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an `application.yml` file which contains a `broker-url` parameter

```
artemis:
  broker-url: "tcp://localhost:61616?consumerWindowSize=1048576&ha=true&retryInterval=100&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.5&maxRetryInterval=60000&reconnectAttempts=10000"
```

My question is how can I separate `tcp://localhost:61616` part from `?consumerWindowSize=1048576&ha=true&retryInterval=100&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.5&maxRetryInterval=60000&reconnectAttempts=10000"`

**Update NO. 1** my project layout[image]

**Update NO. 2**

So, what I was after was something like this

```
ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory f =
 new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory(brokerUrl + ":" +brokerPort + brokerParams);
```

and that I have achieved by changing my `application.yml` like this

```
artemis:
  broker-url: "tcp://localhost"
  broker-port: "61616"
  broker-params: "?consumerWindowSize=1048576&ha=true&retryInterval=100"
```

NOTES: I'm using `spring boot 2.4.0`

And now I can call my jar artifact like this

```
   java myjar.jar --broker-params="?consumerWindowSize=1048576" --broker-port="1111" --broker-url="tcp://192.168.1.2"
```

Comment: Where is `application.yml` file used?

Comment: Why would you want to separate them?

Comment: I want to separate them so that I could have a default option with the ability to change
ip address, port and broker parameters on startup

Comment: Is changing these values as part of the `broker-url` not an option for you?

Comment: you mean  to pass a whole broker-url with all parameters at runtime? If so, then no, full broker-url is just way too long. And in this case I was looking for ways on how to configure only particular parts of that broker-url, namely FQDN and port.

Comment: is the way described in updated 2 is a no go or is considered a bad practice or an antipattern of some sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActiveMQ Artemis properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisProperties.java) for Spring Boot allow to set the host, the port and other parameters only using the `broker-url` property.

You could try using [a placeholder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties) as workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to separate the URL parameters from the URL. In fact, the whole point of the URL is to have everything together.